# IIS Manager Not showing the list of sites in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, iis

My guess is that the file applicationHost.config is corrupted, therefore the list of sites or application or not visible under the main IIS node.


Is there a way to find the original applicationHost.config that is used in 8.1?

Uninstalling and re-installing IIS did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you adding a new node to a web farm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AppCmd.exe`. It is located in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`.

First, you use `appcmd list backup` to display all the available backups. Then you pick out a proper backup and use `appcmd restore backup <backup name>` to recover IIS.

Comment: I have no backups, this computer is freshly installed.